# Good and reliable books editions about pujas and Vastu?

Tags: scripture, astrology, dharma-shastras, puja, vastu-shastra

Where to find complete Shastras or others like Agamas scriptures in order to know Why and How certain foods or flowers or scents are more appreaciated by a Deva if compared to something other to offer to Them?

E.g. Offering of vermillion or red flowers to Hanuman, milk or ghee to Shiva etc.

In Rig Vedas translation something is mentioned but unfortunately my edition is not a critical one and plus I do not know with precision about Vastu and Pujas offers from authorative texts but I keep on find several contradictories articles online.